# use pandas groupby to group multiple columns

Tags: pandas, excel, dataframe

I have imported a `.xlsx` file with multiple tabs (around 3 million rows) where column headers exist on first tab only, just data with no headers on remaining tabs. I now have a pandas datafreamne with some information that won't be required removed;

```
import pandas as pd

#load in .xlsx with multiple tabs as a dataframe
filepath = "Consumption_20221111_testdata.xlsx"
df_dict = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=None, header=None)
df_all = pd.concat(df_dict.values(), ignore_index=True)
df_all = df_all.drop(columns=df_all.columns[2]) #remove column "PERIOD_ID"
df_all = df_all.drop(columns=df_all.columns[2]) #remove column "DATA_FLAG"
df_all = df_all.drop(df_all.index[-1]) #remove the last row (details of query run on SQL database that produced .xlsx which is the last tab of the .xlsx)
df_all = df_all.dropna(how='all') #remove columns that are all 'NaN'
df_all[1] = pd.to_datetime(df_all[1][1]) #convert column from object to datetime
print(df_all)
print(df_all.dtypes)
```

My dataframe has an index noted for column and rows, but the date column now has a date instead of a header?

|  | 0 | 1 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | REF | 2022-10-12 | CONS |
| 1 | REF1 | 2022-10-12 | 0.262 |
| 2 | REF2 | 2022-10-12 | 0.259 |
| 3 | REF2 | 2022-10-12 | 0.405 |

I need to group the data on reference and date, aggregating the consumption to compare month to month but first I need to have a dataframe I can reference!

```
df_all["Month"] = df_all[1].dt.month
df_all = df_all.groupby(by=[1, "Month"], as_index=False).agg({"CONS":sum})
df_all
```

resulted in;

> **KeyError**: "Column(s) ['CONS'] do not exist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposition using method chaining :

```
df_all = (
            pd.concat(pd.read_excel("Consumption_20221111_testdata.xlsx",
                                    header=None, sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
                .T.set_index(0).T
                .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
                .loc[:, ["REF", "DATE", "CONS"]]
                .assign(MONTH= lambda x: x["DATE"].dt.month)
                .groupby(by=["DATE", "MONTH"], as_index=False).agg({"CONS":sum})
         )
```

##### # Output :

```
​
print(df_all)

        DATE  MONTH  CONS
0 2022-10-12     10  5.25
```

*NB: The input Excel was made with some of the rows you shared plus some random values.*

[image]

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Scripts\script.py", line 2, in <module>
    pd.concat(pd.read_excel("Consumption_20221111_testdata.xlsx",
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined. Did you mean: 'id'?

Comment: I received the above error, I'm not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: You need to put this line before the code: `import pandas as pd`

Comment: well now I feel silly!

Comment: No worries my friend, it happens to all of us. Happy coding ;)